# How to pick image from camera and gallery , crop it and set to image view

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

Please help me i have a written a code so far that can pick an image from both camera and gallery and display it, but i find it difficult to crop it. I am trying to use a third party android library called android image cropper, but finds it difficult to implement.I have played around with the code but nothing useful coming up. in other words i am trying to achieve the effect obtainable in whasap where you click a button to upload profile picture, it sets it to crop and then display a circular view of the image. here is a link to the android library [android image cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper). any help will be appreciated thank you all.

here is my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0, SELECT_FILE = 1;
    private Button btnSelect;
    private ImageView ivImage;
    private String userChoosenTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSelect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
        btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectImage();
            }
        });
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
                    //code for deny
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result=Utility.checkPermission(MainActivity.this);

                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                    if(result)
                        cameraIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    userChoosenTask ="Choose from Library";
                    if(result)
                        galleryIntent();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    // Ezphoto picker  in action

    private void galleryIntent()
    {
        EZPhotoPickConfig config = new EZPhotoPickConfig();
        config.photoSource = PhotoSource.GALERY;
        config.needToExportThumbnail = true;
        config.exportingThumbSize = 200;
        config.exportingSize = 1000;
        EZPhotoPick.startPhotoPickActivity(MainActivity.this, config);
    }

    private void cameraIntent()
    {
        EZPhotoPickConfig config = new EZPhotoPickConfig();
        config.photoSource = PhotoSource.CAMERA;
        config.exportingSize = 1000;
        EZPhotoPick.startPhotoPickActivity(MainActivity.this, config);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode != RESULT_OK){
            return;
        }

        if(requestCode == EZPhotoPick.PHOTO_PICK_REQUEST_CODE){
            try {
                Bitmap pickedPhoto = new EZPhotoPickStorage(this).loadLatestStoredPhotoBitmapThumbnail();
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(pickedPhoto);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

here is my xml code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Photo" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```